# How to work with excel programatically from other language than VBA?

Tags: java, excel, report

i want to programatically interact with Excel, i am interested mainly in java languag (but can be done in others!)

1. open template workbook
2. get data from csv files and propagate into different worksheets (replace curret set of data or remove and create new sheets)
3. write data as tables
4. save export

Maybe somebody had the similar issue to solve?

thank you!

Best,
Jacek

Comment: You can look at some Java libs for interacting with Excel. One of them is Apache POI: https://poi.apache.org/

Answer (score 1):

I think that **python** can do the job in this case if you would like to decide for its.

*Step 1. "Get template excel data"*

You can use **read_excel** from pandas library.
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html
I.e.:

```
import pandas as pd
first_template = pd.read_excel('tmp.xlsx', sheet_name=0)
```

*Step 2. "Get csv data"*

You can use **read_csv** from pandas library.
I.e.

```
import pandas as pd
csv = pd.read_csv('source_file.csv')
```

*Step 3a. "Replace current data at template with new data from csv."*

You can use various pandas functions on csv variable to get the data you need and assign it to variables like: first_indicator, current_data, acceptance_status (it is hard to me to give you an example, because I do not know how your csv file looks like).

*Step 3b. "Replace current data at template with new data from csv."*

You can insert variables values from step 3b into dataframe from step1 using '**iloc**' and '**loc**' functions in pandas library.

*Step 4. "Write data as tables"*

You can create tables using **xlsxwriter** library in Python.
Here is an example of creating Excel table object.
https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_tables.html

*Step 5. "Save to xlsx"*

You can do it with **pandas** using engine **xlsxwriter** or directly using xlsxwriter library.

I hope that those answer will be useful :)
If you have any questions - feel free to ask.

***Extra tip about ranges styling***

If you decide to save your data as range (not Excel table object) here is some sample of code that can help you to format columns properly.

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(file_path, engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
                
                # reports is a variable that is a dictionary of dataframes
                for report in reports.items():
                    report[1].to_excel(writer, sheet_name = report[0], index=True)
                    workbook = writer.book
                    worksheet = writer.sheets[report[0]]
                    
                    # applying some custom styles for columns
                    for a, b in [(1, 1), (3,3), (8,13), (15, 16), (21,25)]:
                        worksheet.set_column(a, b, 26, workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#,##0.00', 'align':'center', 'text_wrap': 'True'}))
                    for a, b in [(4,5), (7,7), (17,20)]:
                        worksheet.set_column(a, b, 26, workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#,##0.00%', 'align':'center', 'text_wrap': 'True'}))
                    for a in (0, 2, 6, 14):
                        worksheet.set_column(a, a, 26, workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#,##0', 'align':'center', 'text_wrap': 'True'}))
                    header_format = workbook.add_format({'bold': True, 'text_wrap': True, 'valign': 'center', 'fg_color': '#D7E4BC', 'border': 1, 'align':'vcenter'})
                    for col_num, value in enumerate(report[1].columns.values):
                        worksheet.write(0, col_num + 1, value, header_format)

                    # and at least freezing panes
                    worksheet.freeze_panes(1, 1)
```